# View main wrapper markup (div.view) not getting rendered though view content gets rendered

Tags: 7, views, panels

One of my view 'Stylist Analytics' has a **block** display - 'Sales' which is getting rendered in such a way that its **main wrapper markup** **(div.view)** is missing and simply view fields' markup gets rendered along with the pager though all other views work fine in this regard. So, this cannot be possibly a global view setting and has to be specific to this view. I am not sure but probably there is no such setting in a view to enable/disable rendering/appending of view main wrapper markup. I have tried using this view block in panel pane, quicktabs, mini-panel but they all exhibit the same view markup. I'm using Views v3.13 .

Here's the export of my view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'stylist_analytics';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'commerce_commission';
$view->human_name = 'Stylist analytics';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['disable_sql_rewrite'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Commerce commission: Order */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['order_id']['id'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['order_id']['table'] = 'commerce_commission';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['order_id']['field'] = 'order_id';
/* Field: COUNT(Commerce commission: Order) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['id'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['table'] = 'commerce_commission';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['field'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['order_id']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: SUM(Commerce commission: Commission amount) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['id'] = 'commission_amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['table'] = 'commerce_commission';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['field'] = 'commission_amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['group_type'] = 'sum';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['short_scale_check'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = '<div class="hns-merchant-analytics-info">
<div class="hns-merchant-analytics-number">[order_id]</div>
<div class="hns-merchant-analytics-text">Sales</div>
</div>
<div class="hns-merchant-analytics-info">
<div class="hns-merchant-analytics-number">[commission_amount]</div>
<div class="hns-merchant-analytics-text">Commission</div>
</div>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Commerce commission: User */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'commerce_commission';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

/* Display: Analytics */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Analytics', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default_row_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['row_class_special'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['default_field_elements'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Sales */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Sales', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['css_class'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['css_class'] = 'custom-class';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['use_ajax'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_ajax'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['group_by'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['query'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['disable_sql_rewrite'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['distinct'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'load_more';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '3';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['effects']['speed'] = 'slow';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['header'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['empty'] = FALSE;
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'The products you endorsed haven\'t been purchased yet';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'full_html';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['relationships'] = FALSE;
/* Relationship: Commerce commission: Order */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['order_id']['id'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['order_id']['table'] = 'commerce_commission';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['order_id']['field'] = 'order_id';
/* Relationship: Commerce Order: Referenced line items */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['id'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['table'] = 'field_data_commerce_line_items';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['field'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['relationship'] = 'order_id';
/* Relationship: Commerce commission: Product */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['product_id']['id'] = 'product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['product_id']['table'] = 'commerce_commission';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['product_id']['field'] = 'product_id';
/* Relationship: Commerce commission: Product node */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['node_id']['id'] = 'node_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['node_id']['table'] = 'commerce_commission';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['node_id']['field'] = 'node_id';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Path */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['id'] = 'path';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['field'] = 'path';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['relationship'] = 'node_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'node_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Designer */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['id'] = 'field_designer';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['table'] = 'field_data_field_designer';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['field'] = 'field_designer';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['relationship'] = 'node_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['ui_name'] = 'Designer';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['element_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['settings'] = array(
  'link' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_designer']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Commerce Product: Images */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['id'] = 'field_product_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['table'] = 'field_data_field_product_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['field'] = 'field_product_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['relationship'] = 'product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['element_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'line_image_medium',
  'image_link' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['group_column'] = 'entity_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['delta_limit'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['delta_offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_product_images']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Commerce Product: SKU */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sku']['id'] = 'sku';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sku']['table'] = 'commerce_product';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sku']['field'] = 'sku';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sku']['relationship'] = 'product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sku']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sku']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sku']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['sku']['link_to_product'] = 0;
/* Field: Commerce Product: Price */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['id'] = 'commerce_price';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['table'] = 'field_data_commerce_price';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['field'] = 'commerce_price';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['relationship'] = 'product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['element_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['click_sort_column'] = 'amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['settings'] = array(
  'calculation' => '0',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['group_column'] = 'entity_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Commerce commission: Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['table'] = 'commerce_commission';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['date_format'] = 'medium';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['created']['second_date_format'] = 'search_api_facetapi_YEAR';
/* Field: Commission amount */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['id'] = 'commission_amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['table'] = 'commerce_commission';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['field'] = 'commission_amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['ui_name'] = 'Commission amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commission_amount']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Global: Custom text */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = '  <div class=\'order-image\'>
    <a href="[path]">[field_product_images]</a>
  </div>
  <div class=\'order-info\'>
    <div class=\'order-item-brand\'>[field_designer]</div>
    <div class=\'order-item-title\'><a href="[path]">[title]</a></div>
    <div class=\'order-item-total\'>[commerce_price]</div>
  </div>
  <div class=\'order-other-info\'>
    <div class=\'order-item-date\'>[created]</div>
    <div class=\'order-item-sku\'>[sku]</div>
  </div>
  <div class=\'order-link\'>
    <div class=\'commission-sale-item-info-right-commission\'>[commission_amount]</div>
  </div>';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['element_type'] = 'div';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['sorts'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Commerce Order: Line items (commerce_line_items) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['id'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['table'] = 'field_data_commerce_line_items';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['field'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['relationship'] = 'order_id';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['commerce_line_items_line_item_id']['order'] = 'DESC';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
```

Here is the markup that gets rendered:

```
<div id="quicktabs-tabpage-quicktabs_stylist_commission-1" class="quicktabs-tabpage"><div id="block-views-stylist-analytics-block-1" class="block block-views">


  <div class="content">





  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing">        <div class="field-content">  <div class="order-image">
  <a href="/watchjewelry/9-carat-gold-acorn-cufflinks"><div class="field field-name-field-product-images field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><img src="https://honeandstrop.qed42.webfactional.com/sites/default/files/styles/line_image_medium/public/product_images/image.jpg?itok=V1SmL8lc" width="180" height="150"></div></div></div></a>
</div>
<div class="order-info">
  <div class="order-item-brand"><div class="field field-name-field-designer field-type-entityreference field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">Emma Willis</div></div></div></div>
  <div class="order-item-title"><a href="/watchjewelry/9-carat-gold-acorn-cufflinks"></a><a href="/watchjewelry/9-carat-gold-acorn-cufflinks">9 Carat Gold Acorn Cufflinks</a></div>
  <div class="order-item-total"><div class="field field-name-commerce-price field-type-commerce-price field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">$2,000.00</div></div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="order-other-info">
  <div class="order-item-date">14/10/2016 22:49</div>
  <div class="order-item-sku">EM00011</div>
</div>
<div class="order-link">
  <div class="commission-sale-item-info-right-commission">$0.50</div>
</div></div>  </div>    
<div class="views-field views-field-nothing">        <div class="field-content">  <div class="order-image">
  <a href="/accessories/tie"><div class="field field-name-field-product-images field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><img src="https://honeandstrop.qed42.webfactional.com/sites/default/files/styles/line_image_medium/public/blackbird-black-ties.jpg?itok=Z0pAGlZE" width="180" height="150"></div></div></div></a>
</div>
<div class="order-info">
  <div class="order-item-brand"><div class="field field-name-field-designer field-type-entityreference field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">Audemars Piguet</div></div></div></div>
  <div class="order-item-title"><a href="/accessories/tie"></a><a href="/accessories/tie">Tie</a></div>
  <div class="order-item-total"><div class="field field-name-commerce-price field-type-commerce-price field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">$50.00</div></div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="order-other-info">
  <div class="order-item-date">07/10/2016 04:22</div>
  <div class="order-item-sku">Test Tie</div>
</div>
<div class="order-link">
  <div class="commission-sale-item-info-right-commission">$5.00</div>
</div></div>  </div>    
<div class="views-field views-field-nothing">        <div class="field-content">  <div class="order-image">
  <a href="/apparel/black-tuxedo"><div class="field field-name-field-product-images field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><img src="https://honeandstrop.qed42.webfactional.com/sites/default/files/styles/line_image_medium/public/BC27.jpg?itok=34eriI_m" width="180" height="150" alt="BLACK TUXEDO" title="BLACK TUXEDO"></div></div></div></a>
</div>
<div class="order-info">
  <div class="order-item-brand"><div class="field field-name-field-designer field-type-entityreference field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">KITON</div></div></div></div>
  <div class="order-item-title"><a href="/apparel/black-tuxedo"></a><a href="/apparel/black-tuxedo">BLACK TUXEDO</a></div>
  <div class="order-item-total"><div class="field field-name-commerce-price field-type-commerce-price field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">$8,500.00</div></div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="order-other-info">
  <div class="order-item-date">26/09/2016 10:00</div>
  <div class="order-item-sku">kt98008</div>
</div>
<div class="order-link">
  <div class="commission-sale-item-info-right-commission">$850.00</div>
</div></div>  </div>
<div class="item-list"><ul class="pager pager-load-more"><li class="pager-next first last"><a href="/user/455/analytics?page=2">Load more</a></li>
</ul></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked if any template written for this view?

Comment: There is no template for rendering of this view. I am currently using this view block in a quicktab which in turn is being used in a Panel page.  Though this panel page also contains a custom block for which a template has indeed been used but it's separate from the concerned View block.

Comment: @NikhilBanait after looking into view theming information, I actually found a template overriding a display output and the main wrapper div is missing over there. Thanks for narrowing it down.

Comment: cool, great!!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into view theming information, I actually found a template overriding the Display Output and the main wrapper div was missing over there.